# Can the source IP of an ICMP reply message be altered with rules like iptables?

Tags: centos, networking, icmp

I have set up `ip_forward=1` and `rp_filter=2` on CentOS 7, which has two network interfaces:

- eth0 192.168.89.100/24
- eth1 192.168.66.200/24

**I hope that after eth1 receives an ICMP request, it will respond via eth0.** Therefore, I constructed an ICMP message, modified its source IP to 192.168.89.50 (even though it was sent from 192.168.66.xx). My device did respond via eth0 upon receiving this message, but the source IP of the response message remains that of eth1. I captured a packet on eth0 using tcpdump:

```
icmp reply 
src ip: 192.168.66.200 (IP of eth1) 
dst ip: 192.168.89.50
src mac: mac of eth0
```

Could I possibly modify the source IP of the response message to align with the MAC address, so that **both are associated with eth0**? I have tried setting up NAT policies but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: I think you maybe need to be a little more detailed about what you are trying to do. AFAIK ICMP responses always need to have the source IP that was in the destination IP of the request, otherwise the response cannot be matched to the request.  In any case, Linux doesn't strongly bind an IP to an interface (as you've discovered), AFAIK that's only used to know which IPs to remove if the interface is removed. Any interface can send or receive as any of the machine's IPs.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to send selected packet through a specific interface? That's a different question altogether, previously answered elsewhere on Unix&Linux